# Use disk memory to run a highly memory requiring Java program

Tags: java, memory, memory-management

I want to run a Java implementation of the solution to travelling salesman problem using dynamic programming. This program seems to consume large amounts of RAM memory. I used a '-Xmx "memory"' argument to increase the size of RAM memory I am using to 16 GB, but it seems that I need more memory to run the program with the number of cities needed.

I was wondering if there is a way to use the disk space with Java to run such a memory consuming program?

Comment: There's not going to be a simple 'throw this in to make it work' solution there. You can try to just give Java ton of memory and configure your OS to offload that to disk as needed (look up 'virtual memory' or 'swap space'), that's not going to very compatible across systems. You may have to redesign your program to offload things to temporary files manually, and only retain what's actively being used in memory, if you want a more portable solution. As for how to do that, it's going to depend highly on your situation and program architecture.

Comment: How big is your problem, i.e. about how many cities are you writing? Maybe you just need a better algorithm...

Comment: I am testing this benchmark: **bays29** (29 cities). I could only run it with 24 cities. The memory required to solve this problem is much higher my than RAM size.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try Terracotta BigMemory?

https://www.terracotta.org/products/bigmemory